# PHP echo selected values (checkboxes) with different name

Tags: php, echo

How can I echo the list of selected checkboxes, if these have a different name, but the same id.  The different names are required for another function, so I won't be able to change it to the same name.

PHP code

```
$tiles = $_POST['??'];
  if(empty($tiles)) 
  {
    echo "";
  } 
  else
  {
    $N = count($tiles);

    echo("Tiles Selected: <br> ");
    for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++)
    {
      echo ("-" . $tiles[$i] . " <br> ");
    }
  }
```

HTML code

```
<div class='material' id='material1'>
<a class='product'>
<div class='tiles_bg' style='background:url(media/images/tile2.jpg);'>
<input class='select_all' id='tile' type='checkbox' name='1marm[]' value='Verde Guatemala'>
</div>
<p>Verde Guatemala</p>
</a>
<a class='product'>
<div class='tiles_bg' style='background:url(media/images/tile1.jpg);'>
<input class='select_all' id='tile' type='checkbox' name='1marm[]' value='Bianco Carrara'>
</div>
<p>Bianco Carrara</p>
</a>
</div>
<div class='material' id='material2'>
<a class='product'>
<div class='tiles_bg' style='background:url(media/images/tile4.jpg);'>
<input class='select_all' id='tile' type='checkbox' name='2gran[]' value='Nero Assolutio'>
</div>
<p>Nero Assolutio</p>
</a>
</div>
<div class='material' id='material10'>
<a class='product'>
<div class='tiles_bg' style='background:url(media/images/GroheEssence.jpg);'>
<input class='select_all' id='tile' type='checkbox' name='10Kok[]' value='Grohe Essence'>
</div>
<p>Grohe Essence</p>
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: When you `POST` data, you only send the `name` and `value` attributes. The `id` attribute isn't sent. Each `id` attribute **should be unique**.

Comment: The `id=` is used by the DOM and javascript all on the client side browser, an `id=` should be unique on any page, so all your fields having `id="tile"` is bad and if you look at the debugger on the browser you should see this being reported as an error. The `name=` and `value=` are used by the browser to generate the $_POST or $_GET arrays used by PHP.

Comment: Also you should know that if a checkbox is NOT CHECKED, it will not be sent to PHP in the `$_POST` or `$_GET` arrays so all you have to do is test for their existance using eg `isset($_POST['10Kok][0])` to know if they where ticked